# How do you intregarte the API key into R Code when using getmap in Rgooglemaps

Tags: r, api, key, satellite-image

Previously I was able to overlay maps of disease on satellite maps. Now it appears that an API key is required. I am unable to integrate this into R code.

So far I have tried accessing a code on google maps. I get a code but I am unable to integrate it into my R code.

```
library(RgoogleMaps)
lat = c(-30.3022,-30.5000,-33.48569)
lon = c(153.1189,151.6500,145.5316)
center = c(mean(lat), mean(lon))
zoom <- min(MaxZoom(range(lat), range(lon)))
mymap <- GetMap(center=center, zoom=zoom, maptype= "terrain", destfile = "MyTile1.png")

Error in download.file(urlStr, destfile, mode = "wb", quiet = TRUE) : 
  cannot open URL 'http://maps.google.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=-31.4292966666667,150.100166666667&zoom=6&size=640x640&maptype=terrain&format=png32&sensor=true'

In addition: Warning message:
In download.file(urlStr, destfile, mode = "wb", quiet = TRUE) :
  cannot open URL 'http://maps.google.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=-31.4292966666667,150.100166666667&zoom=6&size=640x640&maptype=terrain&format=png32&sensor=true': HTTP status was '403 Forbidden'
```

I reckon I will need to include something here that includes the api key for the relevant map

Comment: There is an  API_console_key parameter of GetMap(). I found that here https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/RgoogleMaps/versions/1.4.3/topics/GetMap

Comment: The Google Maps API changed several months ago to require API keys for geocoding. Packages that use the API have to update their functions accordingly. Are you sure you're using the most recent version of this package?

Comment: Thanks Camille. I will try reinstalling RGooglemap. I think this is what you mean?

Comment: Thanks Elin. I see the code on the link. But am having difficulty integrating that into my code above.

Comment: I re-installed Rgooglemaps and integrated the code from Elins link provided with no luck.

> MyMap <- GetMap.bbox(bb$lonR,bb$latR,destfile= "caj.jpg",
+ 
+ API_console_key = Sys.getenv("GOOGLE_MAPS_API_KEY"))  
Error in download.file(urlStr, destfile, mode = "wb", quiet = TRUE) : 
  cannot open URL 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=53.4330179555099,-8.32976373138243&zoom=7&size=640x640&maptype=mobile&format=png32&sensor=true&key='
In addition: Warning message:
In download.file(urlStr, destfile, mode = "wb", quiet = TRUE) :

Comment: `library(googleway)` is an  alternative which works

Comment: How does the term API_console_key = Sys.getenv("GOOGLE_MAPS_API_KEY") get me through to the google maps. I guess I should input the actual key somewhere

Comment: Problem solved. Many thanks Camille and @Elin   I use                    API_console_key = Sys.getenv("AIzaSyBVn2-3kUeTBoCeOJY0aYy2IWP9...…...") This breaks me through into the google map. This discussion may be useful for others as it overcomes a recent change